# Wire and inject NLog into .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I created a consumer/job that I will have running as a process on Linux written in C#.

The process will:

1. Read a message from RabbitMQ
2. Make changes to the database
3. Log any errors

All the documentation on NLog about .NET Core are on ASP.NET Core. When I try to get an `ILogger` implementation, it returns null.

Here is an except of wiring and usage:

```cs
static void ConfigureServices()
{
    string environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory))
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true);

    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    Configuration = builder.Build();

    [...]

    services.AddLogging();

    ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var loggerFactory = ServiceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigureServices();
    
    var logger = ServiceProvider.GetService<NLog.ILogger>();

    logger.Debug("Logging");

    [...]
}
```

Do not be confused with the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`; it is used solely to determine which `appsettings.json` to use.

I've based my code on this [issue report](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/111).

Finally, these are the packages I currently have installed.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.0.0-beta09" />
  <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.0-rtm-beta5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="3.2.4.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Resolve `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` instead of `NLog.ILogger`.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov wont that just give me the msft logger and route all my logs through msft logging?

Comment: Actually, I just tested this, and `logger` is still null.

Comment: my bad, I meant `ILogger<T>`.

Comment: and yes, you receive a generic msft logger. In general it is good due to your code doesn't depend on concrete logger implementation. You could attach and replace it in any time.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A complete minimalistic example of NLog in a .NET Core 1 console app (based on [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging) repository):

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging();
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var factory = provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
factory.AddNLog();
factory.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

var logger = provider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
logger.LogCritical("hello nlog");
```

References:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.0-rtm-beta5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

nlog.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">

  <variable name="Layout"
            value="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"/>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" 
            name="allfile" 
            fileName="nlog-all-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${Layout}" />

    <!-- write to the void aka just remove -->
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

    <!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 14):

In DotNet Core 2 you can use the start up class now and clean up the code a bit to look more like the web one.

And as a bonus a way to start your app inside the DI container using *ConsoleApp*

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

    Startup startup = new Startup();
    startup.ConfigureServices(services);

    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    // entry to run app
    serviceProvider.GetService<ConsoleApp>().Run();
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);

        services.AddSingleton<IMyConfiguration, MyConfiguration>();

        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {
           loggingBuilder.AddNLog("nlog.config");
        });

        services.AddTransient<ConsoleApp>();
    }
}
```

**ConsoleApp.cs**

```
public class ConsoleApp
{
    private readonly ILogger<ConsoleApp> _logger;
    private readonly IMyConfiguration _config;

    public ConsoleApp(IMyConfiguration configurationRoot, ILogger<ConsoleApp> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = configurationRoot;
    }


    public void Run()
    {
        var test = _config.YourItem;

        _logger.LogCritical(test);

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
public class MyConfiguration : IMyConfiguration
{

    IConfigurationRoot _configurationRoot;
    public MyConfiguration(IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot)
    {
        _configurationRoot = configurationRoot;
    }

    public string YourItem => _configurationRoot["YourItem"];
}


public interface IMyConfiguration
{
    string YourItem { get; }
}
```

Answer (score -9):

My solution is to use an adapter pattern that uses Console.Writeline, until a more sane version of NLog becomes available.

```
using System;
public static class Log
{
    public static void Write(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: By using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, then you get stuff like support for structured logging. And the ability to perform dynamic filtering and to replace your logging sink/target with your favorite choice. If you just want console-logging, then no need to choose any logging framework.

Comment: Is this adapter pattern? Doesn’t look like it. I mean if you at least tried Singleton pattern then maybe I’d upvote. This is just a static “global” that violates SOLID. But sure.