# How to use use NLog in .Net core console application?

Tags: .net-core, nlog, .net-standard-2.0

The built-in logging cannot log to file/database. I found the following link however it's for Asp>net core.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017)

How to use NLog in the .Net core console application?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838424/wiring-and-injected-nlog-into-a-net-core-console-application ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wiring and injected NLog into a .Net Core console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838424/wiring-and-injected-nlog-into-a-net-core-console-application)