# What's the correct way to set up NLog for logging in a .NET Core app?

Tags: .net-core, console, nlog

What is the correct way to set up NLog logging for a .NET Core console application?

I see there is mention in [Wiring and injected NLog into a .Net Core console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838424/wiring-and-injected-nlog-into-a-net-core-console-application) of using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger somehow but no example and I'm having the same issue of getting a null.  I tried the other examples in the posting but same thing, null object.

As an update, I got the code below to work by adding using statements for NLog.Config and then using the LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger.  I saw this in another post but I'm not sure why it works or if it's the correct way.  So, I am still hoping someone can enlighten me on the correct way to get NLog setup in .NET Core or if this is the correct way, please let me know.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    //service collection are were we register our services
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

    serviceCollection.AddLogging();

    //service provider is where we get our services
    serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    //logging (ILoggerFactory requires Microsoft.Extensions.Logging dependency and adding a using statement)
    var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

    //NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("NLog.config");

    //AddNLog required adding dependency NLog.Extensions.Logging and then adding a using statement
    loggerFactory.AddNLog().ConfigureNLog("NLog.config");

    logger.Debug("I successfully logged a debug via NLog!");
}
```

Comment: `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` will work just fine and skips Microsoft Extension Logging (MEL). If you want to use MEL, then see the example here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Getting-started-with-.NET-Core-2---Console-application

Comment: Thanks Rolf.  This link was where I saw the LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger() being  used.  I wasn't sure if that was the right way or not to get NLog working as I'm both new to NLog and .Net core and just trying to make sense of everything.

Comment: `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` returns a pure NLog-Logger-object, that will work even if some goes wrong in the setup of MEL. That is why the example code creates this object initially for error-reporting.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most recent way to add and use `NLog` with support for `ASP.Net Core 5` is described on [github](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-5)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using NLog.Web;

namespace ASP.NET_Core_5_NLog_Example
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
            try
            {
                logger.Debug("init main");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //NLog: catch setup errors
                logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
                NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection
    }
}
```